# Cannot remove fragment on screen orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want my app to show one fragment when the device is in portrait mode and two fragments when the device is in landscape mode.

One fragment contains a ListView and is always shown, and the second one contains some more details about the selected list item and is only shown on landscape mode.

The first fragment communicates with the app using the communicator pattern.

I have set two layout files, one for each orientation, and everything works fine.

The problem is, when I run the app on landscape mode and rotate it back to portrait, the second fragment, though it's not visible, still exists, meaning that:

```
getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.detailsFragment) == null // false
```

I assumed this had something to do with android not shutting down the unnecessary fragments automatically, so in my activity's onCreate method I tried adding:

```
if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
    if (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.detailsFragment) != null) {
        Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "There is a details Fragment in portrait mode - removing");
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.detailsFragment)).commit();
    }
}
```

Although the log message is shown, meaning there is no major screwup/typo etc, the fragment is not removed.

I just changed my lists item click handler to log whether there is a detailsFragment in the current configuration or not:

```
@Override
public void listItemClicked(int index) {
    if(getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.detailsFragment) != null){
        Log.v(DEBUG_TAG,"There is a details Fragment");
    } else {
        Log.v(DEBUG_TAG,"No details Fragment!");
    }
}
```

When I run the app on portrait, I get "No details Fragment!" as expected.

When I run it on landscape, I get "There is a details Fragment" as expected.

When I run it on landscape, then switch to portrait, it logs "There is a details Fragment" even though I have removed it.

What am I doing wrong? How can I list all the fragments of my app so I can see where my problem is?

Comment: Why are you trying to remove the `Fragment`? If it has no container in the portrait layout, then it won't have any UI created, and will only be retaining your landscape layout state. In any case, I can't reproduce your issue in either the framework or the support library (using Galaxy S2 with Jelly Bean).

Comment: @corsair992 if the app is in portrait mode, instead of updating the details fragment, it will start a new activity to show the details fragment. Two questions. Isn't just leaving the fragment bad practice? If not, should I just detect the orientation on each click and act accordingly?

Comment: No, leaving the `Fragment` is not a bad practice - the opposite in fact, as it ensures that it's state will be retained upon restoration. You should act according to the _layout_ upon click of a list item (as you might add other criteria than orientation). You can do that by removing the details `Fragment` container in the portrait layout, then checking for the existence of it dynamically. That's how it's implemented in the sample flow in the `Fragment` documentation reference, the `FragmentLayout` sample in the API Demos, and the master/detail flow template in Eclipse and Android Studio.